# Specialize a template function with template class

Tags: c++, templates

I need to write a `parse` function that can parse `string` to other types:

```
OtherType parse(const std::string &s)
```

Since C++ doesn't allow to overload by return value, I tried to use template and template specialization:

```
template <typename T>
T parse(const std::string &s);

template <>
double parse(const std::string &s) { return std::stod(s); }
```

This works, however, I also need to specialize this function with `template <typename T, typename U> std::pair<T, U>` and `template <typename ...Args> std::tuple<Args...>`. Obviously, the following **won't** work:

```
template <>
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> parse(const std::string &s);
```

I **DO NOT** want to modify the `parse` interface as the following, and overload on this function.

```
template <typename T>
void parse(const std::string &s, T &t);
```

In order to keep the interface, I tried the following:

```
template <typename ...>
struct Trait {};

double parse_impl(Trait<double>, const std::string &s);

template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> parse_impl(Trait<std::pair<T, U>>, const std::string &s);

template <typename T>
T parse(const std::string &s) {
    return parse_impl(Trait<T>(), s);
}
```

Although this works fine, I'm wondering is there any better solution? Is there any syntactic sugar can help me to write something like: `template <> template <typename T, typename U> std::pair<T, U> parse(const std::string &s);`

Comment: Better how? You didn't mention what is it you don't like about tag dispatch.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm wondering is there any syntactic sugar can help me to write something like `template <>
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> parse(const std::string &s);`

Comment: I would (and typically do) go with the tag dispatching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class templates, which support [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization); while function templates don't. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct parser {
    static T parse(const std::string &s);
};

template <>
struct parser<double> {
    static double parse(const std::string &s) {
        return std::stod(s);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct parser<std::pair<T, U>> {
    static std::pair<T, U> parse(const std::string &s) {
        return ...;
    }
};

template <typename... Args>
struct parser<std::tuple<Args...>> {
    static std::tuple<Args...> parse(const std::string &s) {
        return ...;
    }
};
```

And add a helper function template,

```
template <typename... T>
inline auto parse(const std::string& s) {
    return parser<T...>::parse(s);
}
```

And use them as,

```
parse<double>("");
parse<std::pair<int, int>>("");
parse<std::tuple<int, int, int>>("");
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TGBkSr2gbdC6YCqM)

Answer (score 0):

You can overload function templates even if their parameters are the same, so just use

```
// overloading, not specialization
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<T, U> parse(const std::string &s);
```